# How to perform a paired paired Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test on imputated data

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, t-test

I would like to perform a paired Wilcoxon Rank Sum on imputated data. Unfortunately, the `testEstimates` function of the `mitml` package needs estimates and standard errors of each imputation. I can extract these data from the result of a t.test but this approach does not work for the Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
library(mice)
library(mitml)
d <- nhanes

imp <- mice(d)
implist <- mids2mitml.list(imp)
complete(imp)

fit <- with(implist, t.test(bmi, chl, paired=TRUE)) # with is a function of the mitml package here
fit

est <- sapply(fit, "[[", "estimate") # extracting estimates
se <- sapply(fit, "[[", "stderr") # extracting standard errors
se
est
testEstimates(qhat = est, uhat = se^2)


fit <- with(implist, wilcox.test(bmi, chl, paired=TRUE))
fit
str(fit[[1]])
```

The structure of the wilcox.test object is as follows:

```
> str(fit[[1]])
List of 7
 $ statistic  : Named num 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "V"
 $ parameter  : NULL
 $ p.value    : num 0.0000131
 $ null.value : Named num 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "location shift"
 $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
 $ method     : chr "Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction"
 $ data.name  : chr "bmi and chl"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

I am looking forward to your help. Maybe a total different approach works for the Wilcoxon rank test.

Comment: *"does not work"* ... what goes wrong? I don't have that package installed, but some errors can be easily explained anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated my question.

Comment: Which command is giving the error? It is not clear in your code. Additionally, you should avoid using `with()` and rather call `implist$bmi` directly.

Comment: Your function argument is not a fitted statistical model and thus has no vcov, read `?testEstimates`.

Comment: I again updated my question.